# How to get the IPAs for multiple targets in a same time (Xcode 7.0 GM)?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift, ipa

I have 10 targets in my project and also added Cocoapods. Its difficult to get individual ipa's and takes too much time. Is there any someother way to get the ipa's in a single time?

Can any one suggest me what is the easy to get the 10 target builds ?

Thanks.

Comment: Bro their is no such way ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell script and call `xcodebuild ... archive` for each target.  If you specify the `-archivePath` argument you can set the archive folder to a local folder then you have access to all of the `.ipa` files generated during the build.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

for target in target1 target2 target3
do
    xcodebuild -project NameOfProject.xcodeproj -configuration Release -scheme $target -archivePath archive.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos archive
done
```

You will find the `.ipa` files for all the targets within the `archive.xcarchive` folder:

```
find archive.xcarchive -name \*.ipa -print
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate me? I didn't get you.

Comment: @Surezz What didn't you understand?  How to write a shell script?  How to invoke `xcodebuild`?

Comment: How to write a shell script?

Comment: @Surezz OK I've added an example.

Comment: Thank you soo much @l00phole. I hope it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Hi 100Phole.... still I didn't try it. I got someother work right now. I ll try and let you know soon.